# Event when flyout is launched (Windows 8 metro app)

Tags: windows-8

i have the problem, that my flyout (in the settings charme) is hidden behind an ad in my application. Now i want to solve this issue by hiding the Ad, when the fylout is selected.

But how can i notice in my page code, that the flyout is selected?

Thanks very much

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do it would be to create an event listener for the `onbeforeshow` event (see documentation here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211723.aspx.) The function you set for the listener can hide the ad.

Take a look at the official documentation for the WinJS.UI.Flyout object itself for more events to which you can subscribe: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br211726.aspx

Comment: Thx very much. The event listener would be put in the page's code and not in the code of the flyout?

Comment: Ah , sorry, i forgot to mention that i am on c# and xaml