# Refer to an element of a another page (Windows 8)

Tags: windows-8

i am using a c# flyout in my windows 8 store app. When i open my custom flyout (i.e. Settings) i want to hide the advertisment that is in the page below the flyout. Is
there a way that i can refer to this Ad within the code of my flyout page?

Thanks very much

Comment: how have you defined the Ad? I mean what is the control name? Also you seem to have another question, is that related to this? 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13634568/event-when-flyout-is-launched-windows-8-metro-app

Comment: yes its related, but i wanted to know generally if i can refer to an element. But when i use for example ad.visibility==visibility.collapse i got an error for sure, because the ad is defined in the page that lies under the flyout, not in the flyout itself

Answer (score 0):

The best practice is to use attached behavior (see nuget package winrtbehavior), you can attach the property and when the popup is loaded you can invoke the command to hide the adcontrol